Can I get compensated for damages (unused train tickets) if my flight is cancelled more than 14 days in advance?

Under the Montreal Convention, air carriers are strictly liable for
proven damages up to 128,821.00 special drawing rights (SDR)...

When I need to travel to Germany I usually I book train tickets far in advance to avoid paying exorbitant fares (E.g. a train ticket that today costs € 140, could be sold for € 23 for the same route, time, and class about 3 months ago). In the past I had a flight delayed by a few hours in which I lost my train connection (not covered by the EC 261), and the airline compensated my train ticket (I mentioned the Montreal Convention in my compensation request).
In this case my flight got delayed when I was in the airport without prior notice. My question is about what happens if the airline cancels the flight more than 14 days in advance. I know for example that the EC261 doesn't require the airline to pay cash compensation when the airline notifies the passengers at least two weeks prior to departure:

The airline is also required to pay cash compensation as described
below, unless one of the following conditions applies:
the airline notifies the passengers at least two weeks prior to departure

However, I couldn't find such exemption under the Montreal Convention and since it covers most flights (including EU flights), I wander if I could claim compensation for unused train tickets if my flight is cancelled more than 14 days in advance?

First of all, you are misquoting the Montreal Convention. Air carriers are liable for damages up to 128,821 SDR 'in Case of Death or Injury of Passengers'. In case of delays, the limit of liability is 5,346 SDR and there is no specified limit in case of cancellations. Note, that these are upper liability limits for the carrier and not a bucket, from which the Convention grants you as a passenger any rights to a certain scoop.

What else? The Convention does not say that the carrier is liable for damages up to  5,336 SDR in case of delays, it limits the liability to  5,336 SDR. That's a very important difference. The Convention does in fact not give you as a passenger any rights in case of a delay at all.

I bet this sort of thing falls under "travel insurance"
